# Stream live video from Spring-boot to React

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, video-streaming, live-streaming

I need to to receive a "live" video stream into a Spring-Boot server and forward it to a React based frontend.
The backend can store the video for the duration of the stream, if needed.

I think I may be lack some basic terminology, as when I tried to search for it I found only tutorials in which the backend sends the video from a ready made file.

For simplicity's sake, let's assume I can decide how the live video is sent to the Spring backend - format etc.

Thank you!